# Is /tmp directory of lambda persistent for a while, or clears it after every run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

For how much time AWS Lambda /tmp directory stores files or it cleans after each run of the function?

Answer (score 4):

From [AWS Lambda Execution Context - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html):

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda **maintains the execution context for some time in anticipation of another Lambda function invocation**. In effect, the service freezes the execution context after a Lambda function completes, and thaws the context for reuse, if AWS Lambda chooses to reuse the context when the Lambda function is invoked again.
>
> ...
>
> When you write your Lambda function code, **do not assume that AWS Lambda automatically reuses the execution context** for subsequent function invocations. Other factors may dictate a need for AWS Lambda to create a new execution context, which can lead to unexpected results, such as database connection failures.

So, it isn't necessarily for a certain time. It mostly depends on resource availability.

Answer (score 4):

If a Lambda is invoked from cold, a new container (or sometimes containers from my own experience) is created/provisioned.

If you write something to the temp folder and call that Lambda again soon after it has finished running, you will likely find what you wrote to the temp folder is still there.

But if you called that Lambda while it is still running from a previous call, you will be redirected to a different container, and therefore the temp drive will be empty.

AWS won't divulge how long a container is kept for and I believe change it fairly often. A container is likely to stay active longer if kept warm (called regularly). But AWS will occasionally flush all the containers regardless. Again AWS won't give a time frame of when this happens as they will change it to suit themselves. I also think it is likely it is dependent on how busy a given region is at a particular time.

In general AWS recommend that you don't rely on a container being the same container that you called on the last invocation. Lambdas are designed for stateless processes. If you need to maintain a state, use external storage like S3 or whatever suits your needs best.